# Spark query of parquet files - error traceback says file is missing... but the file is there. Why?

Tags: python, apache-spark, parquet, apache-spark-sql

I am using parquet files to persist the data in a Spark dataframe using Python.

The parquet appears to be saved correctly, but when it is loaded into a dataframe again, df.show() will generate and error with the traceback indicating that there is a file missing in the parquet directory.

Strangely, an ls command immediately after getting the error shows that the file is there.

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

The relevant portion of the ipynb is included below in plain text:

---

```
In [12]:

#persist this DF as a Parquet File
confirmedSignalsDF.saveAsParquetFile("correctedDoppler.parquet")

In [13]:


# ls shows that the parquet directory and all data files have been properly created
ls -l correctedDoppler.parquet

total 932
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users     0 Oct  5 18:22 _SUCCESS
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users  1118 Oct  5 18:22 _common_metadata
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 41992 Oct  5 18:22 _metadata
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 36268 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00001.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 36631 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00002.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 34087 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00003.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 20103 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00004.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 22344 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00005.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 13438 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00006.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 14898 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00007.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 20501 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00008.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 21550 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00009.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 24827 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00010.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 18216 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00011.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 19561 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00012.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 22652 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00013.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users  6134 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00014.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users  4275 Oct  5 18:18 part-r-00015.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users  7383 Oct  5 18:19 part-r-00016.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users  5188 Oct  5 18:19 part-r-00017.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 26420 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00018.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 22254 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00019.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 28356 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00020.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 15422 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00021.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 17046 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00022.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 19774 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00023.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 28917 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00024.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 24184 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00025.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 21649 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00026.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 22093 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00027.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 19092 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00028.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 16031 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00029.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 10181 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00030.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users  8465 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00031.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 10999 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00032.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 11059 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00033.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 21826 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00034.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 21474 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00035.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 28181 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00036.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 30956 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00037.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 40088 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00038.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 23564 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00039.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 24405 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-00040.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users  4740 Oct  5 18:20 part-r-01021.parquet\

In [14]:


# Load parquet file just saved and then count/show the DF
confirmedSignalsDF = sqlContext.parquetFile("correctedDoppler.parquet")
confirmedSignalsDF.count
confirmedSignalsDF.show(10)
# This will result in a tracebock error saying that one of the data files does not exist...
# But the ls command in the cell immediately below the error shows that this file does exist

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6594c02048b7> in <module>()
      2 confirmedSignalsDF = sqlContext.parquetFile("correctedDoppler.parquet")
      3 confirmedSignalsDF.count
----> 4 confirmedSignalsDF.show(10)

/usr/local/src/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n)
    271         5   Bob
    272         """
--> 273         print self._jdf.showString(n).encode('utf8', 'ignore')
    274 
    275     def __repr__(self):

/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/src/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o140.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.9 in stage 9.0 (TID 4590, yp-spark-dal09-env5-0037): 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d/notebook/notebooks/correctedDoppler.parquet/part-r-00015.parquet does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:381)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:155)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(NewHadoopRDD.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.compute(NewHadoopRDD.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:801)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)


In [15]:

#ls of the file said to be missing shows it is there

ls -l /home/s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d/notebook/notebooks/correctedDoppler.parquet/part-r-00015.parquet

-rw-r--r-- 1 s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d users 4275 Oct  5 18:18 /home/s26e-5a5fbda111ac17-5edfd8a0d95d/notebook/notebooks/correctedDoppler.parquet/part-r-00015.parquet
```